# How to configure logstash filter for log4j messages?

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash

I have a file mylog.log which has following contents.

```
2014-07-02 20:52:39 DEBUG HelloExample:19 - This is debug : ishan
2014-07-02 20:52:39 INFO  HelloExample:23 - This is info : ishan
2014-07-02 20:52:39 WARN  HelloExample:26 - This is warn : ishan
2014-07-02 20:52:39 ERROR HelloExample:27 - This is error : ishan
2014-07-02 20:52:39 FATAL HelloExample:28 - This is fatal : ishan
```

I have the following conf file for logstash

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/ishan/sf_shared/log4jlogs/1-7-2016.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "(^d+serror)|(^.+Exception: .+)|(^s+at .+)|(^s+... d+ more)|(^s*Caused by:.+)"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So, when I run logstash with following command
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f log4j.conf

But it doesn't show anything on console.
So, how to show it on console? also after adding it how to check on ES? And what kind of filter is needed to parse the information in following json format?

```
{
  "severity": DEBUG
  "class": HelloExample
  "message":This is debug : ishan
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use grok for your pattern. Your multiline seems unnecessary since you already only have 1 line logs?  Also, ^d does not annotate a date. Research grok for the correct patterns

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into grok patterns. Check this [link](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns).
This should work for you :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/ishan/sf_shared/log4jlogs/1-7-2016.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => '%{YEAR}[-]%{MONTHNUM}[-]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:class}%{INT} - %{GREEDYDATA:mess}'
        }   
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I tried to start logstash with this and got following error
Unknown setting 'log' for grok {:level=>:error}

Comment: @IshanBhatt Check now.

Comment: Unknown setting 'message' for grok {:level=>:error}

Comment: It shows
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 1
Logstash startup completed
How to check what went in? It didn't show anything on console. Can I check it in elasticsearch??

Comment: But even after putting stdout above if you cannot see anything on console than you can check logstash.log for the errors...or maybe your inout file is empty